# I am findind it dificult to create a box containing text

Tags: html, text, flexbox

[image for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hcGP.jpg)

what am trying to recreate are those three colored boxes containing texts( Education projects, Health programs and food assistance)

i created three divs with a div-container with h2 tags to contain the texts

Comment: Please show us the code of your latest attempt and where you got stuck.